# Cannot select custom typewriter font with fontspec package

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have downloaded FantasqueSansMono-Normal.zip font from [here](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans/releases). I extracted the TTF fonder with the fonts:

```
➜  naulatex git:(logical-markup) ✗ tree TTF
TTF
├── FantasqueSansMono-Bold.ttf
├── FantasqueSansMono-BoldItalic.ttf
├── FantasqueSansMono-Italic.ttf
└── FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf

1 directory, 4 files
```

I want to select this font as a typewriter font for my document. As I understood from `fontspec` package texdoc I should do something like that:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmonofont{TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf}[
    BoldFont = TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont = TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = TTF/FantasqueSansMono-BoldItalic.ttf ]

\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguages{english, russian}


\begin{document}

    Привіт, Світ! Hello, World!

    \texttt{Some tt text}
    
\end{document}
```

But this setup wont work. It produces:

```
fantasque.tex|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf(0)/m' undefined using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 21.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
fantasque.tex|21 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
fantasque.tex|21 error| Missing = inserted for ifdim.
fantasque.tex|21 error| ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The `fontspec` docs says something about true fonts or something like that. I can't get it, is there something wrong with the TTF files or the Fantasque font itself or the way I set it in LaTeX.

The Not So Short Introduction To LaTeX does as I did, just specifies the file paths to fonts. What's wrong?

Any advice how to select this font as tt or general font selection advices?

Comment: use `FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf` not `TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf` and specify `TTF/` via the `Path` key

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Cant believe that the problem was in the `Path` key. It works, thank you! You can post it as answer so I could approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf` not `TTF/FantasqueSansMono-Regular.ttf` and specify `TTF/` via the `Path` key.